# Elasticsearch GROUP BY column HAVING COUNT > x

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by, kibana, having

In SQL if I have an example table my_site_visits showing which pages users of my website have visited:

```
user_id,url
1,index.html
1,index.html
1,foobar.html
1,index.js
2,a.html
2,b.html
2,index.html
3,foo.js
3,foo.js
4,bar.js
```

then I can find users which have visited more than one unique page with e.g.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) unique_pages_visited
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id, url
    FROM my_site_visits
)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING unique_pages_visited > 1
```

Result:

```
user_id,unique_pages_visited
1,3
2,3
```

Is there a method to do this in Elastic, assuming the JSON I added to Elastic is in a similar form e.g.

```
{
    "user_id": n,
    "url": string,
    [Various other Elastic headers]
}
```

Also is it possible to natively do this in Kibana, or do I need to write a script to generate the Elastic query?

Comment: You can try aggregation in elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SQl translate query of kibana

For example 
POST _xpack/sql/translate
{
   "query": "SELECT * FROM IndexName WHERE id=1  ",
   "fetch_size": 10
}

Put your query with your index name with your SQL query and column name (name should match in elastic search).

Please mark answer if it resolves your problem. Thanks

Comment: the translate generates quite a verbose and advanced query, so a real ES query would be better